# Embedded if with Monit

Tags: monit

I am looking for a service that monitors the CPU of a Unix computer (and that can react according to the load) and thought that Monit could do the job but I am in a difficult situation:

I need, according to the CPU load level (>50% / >75% / >95%), different actions. I wrote those lines:

```
check system $HOST
    if cpu > 50% then exec "one.sh"
    if cpu > 75% then exec "two.sh"
    if cpu > 95% then exec "three.sh"
```

But when the CPU load is higher than 95%, monit launches the 3 scripts. I want to monit to launches one the 3 scripts, according to the CPU load.

I looked for embedded if with monit but it does not seem to exist. Otherwise it would have been simple.

Do you have any idea how to make it work?

Have a nice day!

Bibio

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
check system $HOST
        if cpu > 95% then exec "three.sh" 
        if cpu > 75% then 
          if cpu < 95% then exec "two.sh"
        if cpu > 50% then 
          if cpu < 75% then exec "two.sh"
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not work, monit syntaxe does not seem to accept a "if" right after a "then". It requires what they call an action.

Answer (score 0):

If CPU usage more than 95%, it will always execute all the three scripts.

Better you can prioritize the status in your scripts.

But I am sure, if your CPU usage is between 50-70% for longer run, then it will execute the first scripts (one.sh) alone.